# Why is Leia a princess?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia

We learned that her mother was a queen, but this doesn't matter since she was adopted. And she also was completely unaware of her lineage before the revelation preceding the Battle of Endor.

So, why is she considered a princess?

Comment: Because, the epic story is about the nobody villager saving a princess with the help of the old wizard and his own, previously unknown, magic powers.  And, of course, his father's legacy, passed on by the wizard (which may or may not be a sword, but if it is, it's a magic sword).  Star Wars is a retelling of the epic fantasy hero's journey, so she had to be a princess.

Comment: @Jeff gnovice gave us the short answer, but I think It deserve a long answer on the tone of this comment. Example, I suspect that the character of Amidala was defined as a queen to gave her his royal lineage, but those plans changed somehow.

Comment: I considered it, but the question is asking from an in-universe perspective.  I kinda figured that an out-of-universe answer would seem snarky, even if technically correct.

Comment: @jeff thats make sense.

Comment: Because princesses get 10% off drinks.

Comment: @Jeff don't forget that he's helped by a pirate and two faithful retainers.

Comment: "Save the princess, save the Galaxy."

Comment: Have to go with not. not born a princess. [padme was not queen]
not the natural daughter of a monarch. see above
not a close female relative of monarch, especially a son's daughter.
not the wife or widow of a prince. also she doesn't pass the duck/princess test. [ If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.] re: above remark - proving she is not a princess. Dialectic method ftw princess. I'm more saddened that she never gets much force powers. <sniffle> Leia kicks ass cuz she's not a princess. She's a Senator - she's a Rebel. She is Lady Vade

Comment: Monarchies are pretty fluid in the Star Wars universe.  [Naboo *elects* their monarch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo#Domestic_affairs), whatever being elected Queen means, so it's not too far a stretch to think that Alderaan would allow an adopted princess.

Comment: @user41510 - Actually, Padme did serve as queen.  In most countries, once you serve in the supreme executive position, that title stays with you for life.  Their monarchs just don't rule for life.

Comment: @DavRob60:   I know this is super old, but in the question text, did you mean ***ignore*** in the usual English sense of *to willfully not pay attention to* or the French sense which merely means *to be unaware/to not know*?

Comment: @thePopMachine You are right, French is my native language, I mean unaware.

Comment: @DavRob60:   Okay if I edit?

Comment: @ThePopMachine you shall proceed.

Comment: All little girls who run rebellions against oppressive galactic empires are princesses!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Leia was adopted as a baby by [Senator Organa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bail_Prestor_Organa) and his wife [*Queen* Breha Organa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Breha_Organa), thus making her a princess.

Technically, I don't think she could be considered a princess *by birth*, since her mother [Padmé Amidala](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala) was no longer Queen of Naboo at the time of Leia's birth, having taken the position of Senator of Naboo. So it's only via adoption that she has royal status.

Comment: Part of it I think is that by the way I understand it, it was not generally known that she was adopted and that the public image was that she was a real child of Bael and Breha.

Comment: A "princess" is a title not limited to daughters of kings and queens. It just happens to be the title _also_ used for daughters of kings and queens. Whether her mother was a queen or not when Leia was born doesn't make a difference. If she comes from a princely family, she is a princess. And adoption by a queen would also make her a princess. Prince Charles princely title is indeed the "Prince of Wales" (Wales is a principality) and the husband of Queen Elizabeth is also a "prince" despite not being the son of a king or queen.

Comment: "Prince" just means "first" and refers to rulers rather than the ruled. There is, technically, exactly ONE prince per principality. There exist two German words for "prince", "Fuerst" and "Prinz". "Fuerst" is from a Germanic root (like English "first") and "Prinz" is from a Latin root (like "primary"). Both "first" and "primary" derive from the same Indo-European root meaning the same.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm, obviously you've never read War & Peace. Based on that novel, approximately half of pre-revolutionary Russia were "princes".

Comment: That is obvious to you because of my explanation what "prince" means? Your analysis is as far-fetched as it is wrong.

Comment: Great answer, guy who I totally didn't go to high school with or anything.

Comment: This raises an interesting question: Leia's mother died when Alderaan was destroyed.  So one might expect that Leia would have succeeded her as Queen of Alderaan, and should thenceforth have been "Queen Leia" instead of "Princess Leia".  Of course, it's hard to be Queen of Alderaan when there is no Alderaan, but that also makes it hard to be a Princess of Alderaan...

Comment: Are Bill Clinton and George W Bush still referred to as "President?"  Yes.  It's entirely possible that the title stays, so, technically, she'd still be a princess, even if it didn't carry with it eventual succession to the throne.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Unless the Organas had an older boy?... or adopted an older child!

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm - The Duke of Edinburgh is not Prince Philip because he comes from and married into princely families. He's Prince Philip **only** because Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II granted him that title on Feb 22nd, 1957, via Letters Patent. From March 1947 until then, he was not Prince Philip, having renounced his previous Greek and Danish titles to marry Her Majesty. ([citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Philip%2C_Duke_of_Edinburgh#Duties_and_milestones)) It's not some vague entitlement. It's a very specific and structured thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What did I say was the reason for Prince Philip's princely title?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm - I took it (understandably, I think, given the context) that you were using Prince Philip to support your "If she comes from a princely family, she is a princess." premise (which is false in the real world in any of the significant royal systems, I believe; of course, the SW world may be different). If you meant him just as an example of a prince/princess not being the child of a king or queen, then fair enough. :-) (He's the *grandson* of a king, but his father was never king, having multiple elder brothers.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In Liechtenstein both the head of state and his son are "princes". In Monaco the reigning prince is a prince as are most of his immediate family. Some women married to family members are princesses. Which significant royal system has princely families and does it differently?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm - And you will find in both cases there are specific rules, not some vague "comes from a princely family."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You find me beaten by your arguments. You don't even have to give any examples of significant royal systems where a princely family exists where family members are not princes.

Answer (score 8):

Leia was adopted by the Royal Family of the planet, Alderaan. Her adopted mother was Queen Breha Organa of Alderaan and her adopted father was the Viceroy (and Senator) Bail Organa. Leia became a princess because she was adopted into royalty.

After the destruction of Alderaan, Leia is still considered their Princess (and assumed Queen) by the remaining Alderaanians, even though she calls herself either Senator or General.

In the Star Wars canon book *Bloodline* by Claudia Gray, it goes into a bit more depth about Leia's royal roots.
As to whether Leia (and her brother Luke) are royal by birth, the novel makes an attempt to answer this question. Here is one quote from the book that I found interesting:

> 'Leia, I always told you the truth about your mother and how she died. **But I never told you that she was Padme Amidala, former Queen and Senator of the planet Naboo.'**
> A war orphan and **yet a royal by birth?** Surprised as Lady Carise was, she decided it made sense. **Leia's nobility was indeed in her blood....**
>
> *Bloodline by Claudia Gray, page 202*

Comment: upvote for sourcing - new canon source no less

Answer (score 2):

Actually even exhiled Royalty is still consider King and Queen. Like the ones from Greece. Speaking of Greece Prince Philip who you claim was not a Prince by birth was actually born as grandson of both a King and Queen of Denmark and a King and Queen of Greece. As such he was born a Royal Prince.
Upon his marriage to the future(Now Queen) Elizabeth he was made the Duke of Edinburgh. Hence Leia is the Princess of Alderaan. Technically is Queen as they have a population that survived the death star blowing up Alderaan.

Comment: She could opt to call herself *Princess* as she is the heir of something that cannot be inherited any longer. And the people (well anyone except Han) could be calling her *Princess* out of respect for the memory of the Alderaan-that-was (Han, of course, does it just to annoy her).

Answer (score -2):

She was adopted but no one knew this. They believed she was the daughter of a queen by birth. And that isn't changed even though she has no kingdom anymore. When kings and queens are removed from control and a monarchy dissolved they still keep the title and everyone still calls them prince, princess, king, queen, etc.

Comment: Her adoption was widely known to the public on Alderaan