# How did Bail Organa and his wife explain the sudden appearance of a baby girl named Leia?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, princess-leia

At the end of episode 3, Senator Bail Organa brings a baby girl back to his home planet Alderaan. He and his wife, Breha, adopt the girl and raise her in the royal family. He even kept the baby's birth name, Leia.

[This other question asks if Bail Organa told his wife about the baby's parentage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145427/did-bail-organa-tell-his-wife-about-leias-parentage), but I want to know what the royal family told everyone else.

Since royal families are publicly known, **how did the royal family explain to the public where the baby came from?** If Bail Organa said the child was adopted, wouldn't people be curious about the child's origins? If he said the child was related to the royal family, wouldn't people be able to figure out that was false since they would (probably) know all the members of the royal family? Did he say the child was his by another woman? (Eddard Stark got around the questions by saying "Jon Snow is my bastard child." I can imagine Bail Organa saying something similar.)

If I was a Sith Lord and emperor, and one of the senators just announced a new adoption, and I knew that senator was friendly with a pregnant senator who just died under mysterious circumstances, I would send people to investigate the origins of baby Leia Organa.

Comment: i believe that I read something about her actually being adopted by the royal family, which is not unheard of today...

Comment: It was common knowledge that Leia was [an adopted war orphan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143285/20774)

Comment: Padmé was [made to look pregnant at her funeral](https://afrossip.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/20160830-NP_1.jpg), hence there was no investigation into the whereabouts of her children by the few people who knew that she was pregnant.

Comment: There's always the option of going into seclusion for several months, coming back when the baby's still small enough to pass of as being younger than she actually is (per the 1986 reboot, it working the comics for Jonathan and Martha Kent and their (not legally adopted) son, Clark [the seclusion being a matter of a bad winter]).